# How to display last three rows of a database table in android?

Tags: android, database

I am developing an android application in which i have a database table and i want to display only last three rows from the database how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a SQL table has no inherent order, you have to specify something you want to order by, like a date or id and limit the result to 3.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3
```